# GET request gives 404 error express js even though I have a well defined route in my express server

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, http-status-code-404

I am using Jquery's ajax request to get a JSON object from the server however when the request is invoked it gives a 404 error that looks like this:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     profile_data?uid=HW3gAHeiuJbQLMFQMbHA6nNlFUT2&_=1619880251360:1

As far as I am concerned all is done according to standard which is CRUD = Create:POST, Read:GET,Update:PUT and delete: DELETE.
Please let me know of anything in my code is it wrong ?
Here is the get request:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
            $.ajax({
              url: '/profile_data',
              type: 'GET',
              cache: false,
              data: { "uid": uid},
              success: function(data){
                //Instantiate Variables of User Data
                

              }
              , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
              }
            });

          });

        } else {
          Window.locate.assign("/login");
        }
  });
```

This is the server side code:

```
app.get("/profile_data",   function (req, res){
    const current_user = req.body;
    const uid = current_user.uid;
    console.log(uid)
    db.ref("user_file_ref").on("value", snapshot=>{
        snapshot.forEach( dataSnapshot=>{
            if(uid === dataSnapshot.val().user_id){
                getFileFromNet(dataSnapshot.val().ipfs_ref).then( result =>{
                    const hash = JSON.parse(result);
                    let decrypted_string = decrypt(hash);
                    let return_data = JSON.parse(decrypted_string);
                    //console.log("Here!!")
                    res.send(return_data);
                }).catch(err =>{
                    console.log(err);
                });


            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: When the request is invoked, please check the request URL in the browser network section. can you ?

Comment: >https://localhost:3005/profile_data?uid=HW3gAHeiuJbQLMFQMbHA6nNlFUT2&_=1619881415260

Comment: that is the url I am given

Comment: did you check your server ? is it running?

Comment: yesI did, it is running

Comment: @chipegokalinda you can test your backend code using Postman. Make sure you can send the same request to your backend in Postman then you'll have information to test the frontend code.

Comment: @chipegokalinda you need to change something. I've posted the answer, please try it. Thanks

Comment: @chipegokalinda can you please also vote up the answer. Thanks buddy

Comment: Unfortunately I am too noob to place a visible upvote but once I can I'll be back to give you yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the parameter with URL.

Like this:

```
 $.ajax({
          url: '/profile_data/' + uid,
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          // data: { "uid": uid}
```

and on the server-side.

```
app.get("/profile_data/:uid",   function (req, res){
 const current_user = req.params.uid;
}
```